# NSDateComponents returning unexpected result

Tags: ios, nsdatecomponents

I have this piece of code

```
NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:(NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitDay) fromDate:sender.date];
[comps setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];
NSDate *converted = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:comps];
```

**Sender.date** can be output to console like

> 1963-02-23 12:00:00 am +0000

But **comps.day** for UTC is giving me 22. Which I would expected to be 23 since that sender value in UTC is obviously containing day component equal to 23.

Is that somehow related to 12am? What am I missing here?

Thanks!

Comment: It's saying `22`, because it's showing it to you in your own timezone, whereas the string was showing you the date in GMT/UTC/Zulu.

Comment: Consider to use simply `NSDate *converted = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] startOfDayForDate:sender.date];`

Comment: @Rob But I've set up UTC for DateComponents object. So I would expect UTC value it output to log.

Comment: @vadian - No, that will have the same problem. He needs to set the `timeZone` of the `NSCalendar` he uses for the `dateFromComponents`.

Comment: @ViktorKucera - It's not the time zone of the components. It's the timezone of the calendar that you use when extracting the components that matters.

Comment: @Rob Actually setting the time zone of the components seems to cause the problem.

Comment: Thank you both guys. I want to that input date sender.date transform to UTC start of day. So simply using startOfDayForDate will not help me. Rob please post an answer I will mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends upon your intent. Consider:

```
NSString *string = @"1963-02-23 12:00:00 am +0000";
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a X";
NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:string];
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
calendar.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0];
NSDateComponents *comps = [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitDay fromDate:date];
NSLog(@"%@", comps);
```

This will report:

> <NSDateComponents: 0x610000140420>
>       Calendar Year: 1963
>       Month: 2
>       Leap month: no
>       Day: 23

I can then convert that to a date in our local timezone with:

```
NSDate *converted = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:comps];
NSLog(@"%@", converted);
```

That will show that as midnight in my local timezone (GMT-8), which is 8am in GMT:

> 1963-02-23 08:00:00 +0000

But when I use a formatter to show this to the user, though, it shows that to me in my local timezone:

```
NSDateFormatter *outputFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
outputFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterMediumStyle;
outputFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterMediumStyle;
NSLog(@"%@", [outputFormatter stringFromDate:converted]);
```

That will show:

> Feb 23, 1963, 12:00:00 AM

Obviously, use `timeStyle` of `NSDateFormatterNoStyle` if you don't want to show the time, but I included it just to show you what was really going on.

Personally, I find all of the above quite convoluted. I'm guessing that the original string was trying to reflect a date independent of any particular time and/or timezone (e.g. a birthday, an anniversary, etc.), then I think that everything is much easier if you omit the time and timezone information from the original string and just capture the date in `yyyy-MM-dd` format and leave it at that. Then that simplifies much of the above code.

I might suggest clarifying your actual intent, why you're doing what you're doing, and we might be able to offer better counsel.

Comment: You are a hero. Thank you very much.